# Unable to edit product when it is backorderd in magento 2.1.4

Tags: magento-2.1, quantity, backorder

I have migrated my site from 1.9.3.0 to 2.1.4. Almost all of the migrated products are back-ordered, that means the quantity is below 0.

The new 2.1.4 site is configured to support back orders as it is described in the documentation: Store - Configuration - Catalog - Inventory - Product Stock Options - Backorders -> 'Allow Qty Below 0'.

**the problem:**

When I try to edit a product that is back-ordered (i.e. Qty < 0) it is impossible I to save it. There is a error message below the Qty box: 'Please enter a valid number in this field.'

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think that while this setting allows you to continue selling and have your inventory levels go below zero, there's a thread over on Git Hub that describes the error of not being able to save a product as based on a javascript validation rule.

Here's the thread and some possible ways to solve this:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7401

I hope this helps!